# Possible have 2 php.ini file or 2 extension_dir in php.ini?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php.ini, mysql5.5

i got **Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\apache2triad\htdocs\index.php on line 8** error. I checked php.ini file and saw extension=php_mysql.dll is uncommented.Everything is normal. But in php.ini file, it show me extension_dir is

**; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "C:\apache2triad\php\extensions"**

when i run phpinfo() it show me this:

extension_dir   C:\php5 C:\php5